# Activity.finish() does not finish activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which has three fragments. I have also overridden the `onBackPressed()` method on my activity. When the user navigates to any of my fragments the standard behaviour of the back button occurs. Except for when I launch a fragment not from its "parent".

**Imagine this:** My activity has no UI. It only has 5 fragments. When the user is on either `fragment1`, `fragment2` or `fragment3` and presses the back button he must get out of the app (ie.by calling finish() in only activity the app has). `Fragment1Child` conceptually is a "child" of `fragment1` and `fragment2Child` is a "child" of `fragment2`. When going from `fragment1` or `fragment2` to their children and pressing back I get the expected behaviour. When though, I go from `fragment3` to `fragment2Child` and then press back I am presented correctly with with `fragment2`. Now when I press back the `Activity.finalize()` method I have is executed but the app is **not** closed. Instead I get back to `fragment3`!

Here is my onBackPressed() method that checks what the is the current fragment shown and decides what to do accordingly

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "MainACtivity.onBackPressed()");
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            Log.d("NIBHA", " Drawere  ++++++++++++++++++++++");
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.fragment_container);
            Log.d("Nibha", "" + fragment);
            if (fragment instanceof DeliveryOrder
                    || fragment instanceof IncomingShipment
                    || fragment instanceof RentalAgreement) {
                Log.d(TAG, "EXITING APP");
                finish();
                return;

            }
            if (fragment instanceof IncomingShipmentDetail
                    && getIntent().getAction().equals("RA")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IS DETAIL CALLED FROM RA");
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new IncomingShipment());
                transaction.commit();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try removing ` super.onBackPressed();`?

Comment: Just tried that. I still get thrown into the fragment3 while i have to finish() app.

Comment: Are you able to see "EXITING APP" in logcat?

Comment: That's the weird stuff, yes I do...

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that super.onBackPressed(); is not being called. Remove return statement and change the following to `else if`:

```
if (fragment instanceof IncomingShipmentDetail
                && getIntent().getAction().equals("RA")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IS DETAIL CALLED FROM RA");
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new IncomingShipment());
            transaction.commit();
        }
```